# Is there any difference between .parent("selector") vs .parent().filter("selector")?

Tags: jquery

In practical usage both `.parent("selector")` and `.parent().filter("selector")` seem to produce the same result, right? Is there any situation where both may not act identically?

If not, all of these methods (i.e., `.parent()`, `.parents()` and `.closest()` provide an inbuilt way to filter the results. What exactly is the purpose of `filter()` then? Where can it be used that doesn't provide an inbuilt filtering mechanism?

Comment: `parent().filter("selector")` will push two element sets into the jQuery object's stack (you would have to call `end()` twice to get the original set back). `.parent("selector")` only pushes one set. That's the only difference I can see there.

Comment: Re: your edit, some of the methods that match elements do not take a selector (e.g. `contents()` or `clone()`). `filter()` is useful in these cases. `filter()` can also take a predicate function rather than a selector, which is more powerful.

Comment: `filter()` is very useful however you are trying to apply it to a trivial case where it provides no benefit

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Would you kindly explain how two element sets will be put into the object's stack? What exactly is the difference? Also, pardon me, I'm new to jQuery and don't necessarily understand the concept of object stacks.

Comment: @Somenath, I could, but the official documentation already does a very good job covering these topics. I refer you to the documentation for [pushStack()](http://api.jquery.com/pushStack/) and [end()](http://api.jquery.com/end/).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thank you..